# OpenVPN TLS HandShake Failed with Linux Server/Windows Client

Tags: 16.04, vpn, windows-10, openvpn, tls

I recently bought a Odroid C2 with Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. I have installed OpenVPN to be able to have access from everywhere to my home network. I have Samba sharing folders...

I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have TLS problems when I try to connect my Windows 10 client to the server with the OpenVPN GUI for Windows.

```
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

OpenVPN GUI Log:

```
Fri Jun 10 22:56:35 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.11 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016
Fri Jun 10 22:56:35 2016 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Fri Jun 10 22:56:35 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09
Fri Jun 10 22:56:35 2016 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Fri Jun 10 22:56:35 2016 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET](My address IP):1194
Fri Jun 10 22:56:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1465613796,WAIT,,,
Fri Jun 10 22:57:36 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Fri Jun 10 22:57:36 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Fri Jun 10 22:57:36 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Fri Jun 10 22:57:36 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1465613856,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
Fri Jun 10 22:57:36 2016 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Fri Jun 10 22:57:38 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Fri Jun 10 22:57:38 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Jun 10 22:57:38 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET] (My address IP):1194
Fri Jun 10 22:57:38 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1465613858,WAIT,,,
```

My client configuration (.ovpn file) without the text in comment:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote (My address IP) 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
key-direction 1

(The ca.crt, the client.crt and the client.key files are include in the ovpn file)
```

My server configuration (server.conf) without the text in comment:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

On my router I set the Port Forwarding for the 1194 port with the Odroid IP address:
[see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT57q.png)

I also try the TCP proto but it retry the connection every 5 seconds.

Can you help me please! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you are connecting to correct public IP address then Ubuntus firewall might be blocking the connection.
OpenVPN works for me with following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

And ofcourse need to save the rules. Iptables-persistent is nice tool for this:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

After it's installed, you can save/reload iptables rules anytime:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save 
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent reload
```

For further troubleshooting you could monitor the traffic from server side to see if anything is reaching port 1194:

```
sudo apt-get-install ngrep
ngrep port 1194
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! But it's not working, maybe it's my crappy router. And ngrep gives me nothing :( so there's no port 1194 communication. I'll probably buy a DD WRT router to own my openVPN server...

Comment: It would be nice if you could connect Odroid directly to the internet and if it still won't work then it's probably your internet service provider problem.

Comment: With some research on internet, my internet service provider blocks home server. I probably have no choice and change my internet provider..